# Exchange Online Transport Rule

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Can I use transport rules or another feature in exchange online to accomplish the following:

When a customer sends an email to accounting@contoso.com, a shared mailbox, either in the To or CC field and other contoso employees are on To/CC that we only deliver to accounting@contoso.com and not jim bob and sally?

If this is possible then what would happen if we were to reply all from accounting@contoso.com?

Will jim bob and sally still show up in the To/CC field of the email that was delivered to accounting@contoso.com even though it was not delivered to them. Looking for visibility from the accounting@contoso.com mailbox.

Thank you in advance for your time and replies.

Edit: further clarification from the department requesting if this helps with the answer.

1. Customer emails accounting@contoso.com, support@contoso.com, individual analysts, and other employees at customer's company.
   a.  We end up with multiple email trails all responding to the customer, crossing over each other and ultimately creating confusion for the customer
   b.  Support will do their part and then email accounting to ask them something – accounting already has a ticket, and a new one is created.
   i.  The analyst might do the same
   ii. Customer support in India gets involved in this too

Comment: I don't understand the "From a customer" part - a sender will not be in `To` or `CC` header, a sender will be in `From`

Comment: accounting@contoso.com is in the to/cc field. sorry for the confusion. edited post for clarity.

Comment: About your updated question - Issues like yours are the reason why helpdesk systems exist and sell well (*hint)

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
If sender outside the organisation
 And To/cc contains accounting
Then delete
Except If recipient is accounting
```

Should work for the first part. No this should not affect the actual mail headers, but you could add an additional rule like

```
If Recipient is accounting
  And Sender is outside the organisation
Then
  Remove header 'to'
  Add recipient to 'to' - 'accounting'
```

This replaces the 'to' header. Exchange is pretty particular about it's 'to' headers, so I actually would not be surprised if that one stopped working at some point.

Then, since at least the GUI does not support multiple actions of the same type within a single rule, you'll need yet-another-rule to remove the CC:

```
If Recipient is accounting
  And Sender is outside the organisation
Then
  Remove header 'cc'
```

***Absolutely*** test this first with a separate mailbox!

Comment: I don't understand why i would want to do the first part.

Comment: Well, it's been a bit, but as I understand it, transport rules apply to messages, not "mails", so if you have two addresses in "to", that makes two messages

Comment: alright i'll give it a try

Comment: looking through gui and powershell and can't figure out how to set "if recipient is not accounting", any thoughts?

Comment: Edited the answer - yeah there is no negation, but you can add an except-if which should act like that --- through GUI, don't know about Posh.

Comment: got an error, unable to set "To" to accounting

Comment: I'm probably a bit out of my depth at this point. I made a quick test, and you can actually remove the 'to' header, then add a specific user to the 'to' box, and that will even affect the mail delivery (which I did not expect). Though I wasn't able to add another `remove cc header`, maybe it's possible through posh commandlets, but with the GUI I'd then have to add another rule that actually removes the CC separately... I'll update the answer, but if that doesn't do it I'll have give up :)